# Are safari versions bonded to os x version?

Tags: macos, safari

Am I able to have the latest version of Safari without having the latest version of OS x? Or is that only possible when you update to the latest version of the OS X?

Comment: Is there something specific you're trying to do? Latest changes from moment to moment so if you could narrow down a specific version numbers are even ranges of numbers we might be able to help with the more accurate answer.

Comment: Its doesn't matter what am trying to do. My question is pretty clear. Simply asking if I can update to the latest version without having the latest os.

Comment: The latest version of Safari as of today, the latest version of Safari as of next Spring? Also, "without having the latest os" is rather broad, you could be running 10.4 for instance.

Comment: @AndreFerraz Aah - you're simply on an older OS. I've edited it so it doesn't get closed at too broad. See the [help] about what makes a good question here. Details matter to avoid closure and make it helpful to others.

Comment: No need to be offended :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/safari-9-for-os-x-yosemite-os-x-mavericks-released/#comments), you can try with the following commands in Terminal:

From Mavericks:

```
softwareupdate -i Safari9.0Mavericks-9.0
```

From Yosemite:

```
softwareupdate -i Safari9.0Yosemite-9.0
```

Comment: Do you think there is a reason why apple allows safari updates to happen only when you upgrade to the latest 0S X?

Comment: @AndreFerraz when El Cap came out, I was still on Yosemite, and I could update to Safari 9.0. They do not tie Safari or iTunes updates to a particular OS X release.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Did app store notify you of updates? Or did you force it with the above commands?

Comment: @AndreFerraz It was in the updates tab. I believe you can download it manually via Apple's support page, it would be the same as those commands, but through a GUI package

Comment: @mgiordi enjoy the votes in your other questions and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, no, the versions are not tied to OSX releases. You can be on 10.10 and still get the minor Safari updates, but (for example) when OSX 10.11 came out a new major version of Safari was released with it, and that was tied to the 10.11 update, so they will on occasion release a Safari version tied to a specific OS version.

Comment: Yeah sounds exactly what am investigating